# How can I draw dotted line using chartjs?

Tags: chart.js

I would like to draw dotted line using chartjs. I did not see any options in creating dotted lines. I feel we need to extend the chartjs to support this. Can some one help me in this?

Answer (score 7):

In `Chart.js 2.1+`, use the `borderDash` option within your dataset. It takes an array of two numbers. [See this codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xONrra)

Comment: The author asked for a **dotted** line, not a **dashed** line (provided in your codepen).

Answer (score 6):

For dotted lines use `borderDash` and `borderCapStyle`. The following example creates a dotted line (3px diameter):

```
data: {
  datasets: [
    {
        data           : data,
        borderWidth    : 3, // set diameter of dots here
        borderColor    : '#ccc',
        fill           : false,
        pointRadius    : 0,
        borderDash     : [0,6], // set 'length' of dash/dots to zero and
                                // space between dots (center to center)
                                // recommendation: 2x the borderWidth
        borderCapStyle : 'round' // this is where the magic happens
    }
  ]
}
```

**Output**

[image: Output]

**Output (better contrast for demonstration)**
[image]

Answer (score 4):

## Drawing a Dotted Line

You don't need to extend the chart, but it would be cleaner to do it that way.

---

**Preview**

### [image]

**Script**

```
Chart.types.Line.extend({
    name: "LineAlt",
    initialize: function () {
        Chart.types.Line.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);

        var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
        var originalBezierCurveTo = ctx.bezierCurveTo;
        ctx.bezierCurveTo = function () {
            ctx.setLineDash([10, 10]);
            originalBezierCurveTo.apply(this, arguments)
        }
    }
});

...

new Chart(ctx).LineAlt(chartData);
```

---

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ahj6u14e/

---

Note - the alternative would be to just override `bezierCurveTo` using the chart object.

This works because `bezierCurveTo` is only used to draw the line. If you wanted to do this for straight lines it wouldn't work because `lineTo` is used for other stuff (axis, grid lines...)

Chart.js 2.0 had a `borderDash` option when I last checked (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/31428640/360067)